# Spacing and indentation

Tags: spacing, indentation

I have this code example:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{exmpl}{Example}

\begin{document}

\begin{exmpl}
\textbf{My first grammar}\\
$G = (\{a, b\}, \{A, B\}, S, P) \: where \: P:\\$
\begin{flalign*}
& A \rightarrow a&\\
& B \rightarrow b&
\end{flalign*}
\end{exmpl}

\end{document}
```

This ends up as:

[image]

**I want to modify my code as follows:**

1. There should be some more vertical space between the line starting with "Example" and the line starting with "G = ".
2. I want less space between the line starting with "G = " and the following flalign. Maybe just a normal line break.
3. I want to indent the flalign environment a little bit.

Any hints on this? Thanks :-)

Comment: @dustin Thanks, `\quad` and `\vspace` work, but: I can't get `\smallskip` or `\bigskip` to show any effect in that case. And is there a way to indent the whole flalign instead of adding `\quad` to each single line in it?

Comment: yes, please :-)

Answer (score 3):

Generally you should avoid `\\` except to end rows of tabular or alignment structures, also `where` is a word so shouldn't be in teh math font.

perhaps

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{exmpl}{Example}

\begin{document}

\begin{exmpl}[My first grammar]
\[G = (\{a, b\}, \{A, B\}, S, P)\]
where $P$
\begin{flalign*}
& A \rightarrow a\\
& B \rightarrow b
\end{flalign*}
\end{exmpl}

\end{document}
```

Using the optional title argument for theorems, which probably isn't bold by default but the formatting can be changed, better that that use `\textbf` directly

`amsthm` allows you to define custom styles, perhaps thsi is closer to your original with no () and a bold note text

```
\makeatletter
\newtheoremstyle{ex}% name
  {3pt}%       Space above
  {3pt}%       Space below
  {}%          Body font
  {}%          Indent amount 1
  {\bfseries}% Theorem head font
  {:}%         Punctuation after theorem head
  {.5em}%      Space after theorem head 2
  {\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{\@ifnotempty{#1}{ }\@upn{#2}}%
  \thmnote{ \textbf{#3}}}%          Theorem head spec (can be left empty, meaning `normal')
\makeatother

\theoremstyle{ex}
\newtheorem{exmpl}{Example}
```

Comment: Thank you, also a nice style. Do you know how to remove the brackets around My first grammar, that are added to the title in the PDF and how to change the font for where / text in this environment?

Comment: @stefan.at.wpf see update

Comment: Thank you David, I meanwhile found that too, should have read the manual \:

Comment: oh, what exactly does   {\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{\@ifnotempty{#1}{ }\@upn{#2}}% do?

Comment: @stefan.at.wpf I just copied the original `plain` style from amsthm.sty and added \bfseries and removed the brackets not sure what @upn does (I could check but..)